# Laravel 5 How to integrate with Prestashop in user login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, prestashop-1.6

In Laravel user login, I want to use Prestashop users data. That's when a user had registered an account in Prestashop, he can also use that registered account to log in to Laravel..

How do I integrate Laravel with Prestashop in user login?
Using an external API or Passport?

Comment: I copy PrestaShop authentication method to my external script (ticket system).
1- generate API to receive email and password on external script
2- Add an action after register on PrestaShop to send email and password to external script API

Comment: hi @MahdiShad I don't really understand, can u elaborate more and any sample code to view? Thanks in advanced